# Knife bootstrap error - Successful authentication but not authorized for this action

Tags: chef-infra, knife

`ERROR: You authenticated successfully to https:<chef_server_url> as <user> but you are not authorized for this action
Response:  missing create permission`

I'm running a pretty basic bootstrap command for a Windows AWS instance

`knife bootstrap windows winrm` ....

Currently running the Chef server on-site and not hosted at this time. I also get the same error using knife to attempt to create a new group. I SSH'd into the Chef server and verified my user is listed when I run

`sudo chef-server-ctl list-server-admins`

so it appears I have been granted server-admins permissions. I also see the same errors when trying to view and create things via the web UI. I've been going in circles almost all day trying to resolve this with no luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be pretty simple after all. From the terminal on the Chef server:

`sudo chef-server-ctl org-user-add <org> <user> --admin`

Docs - https://docs.chef.io/server_users.html

I was able to add myself to the admins group and handle other permission related task from there

Comment: I would like to add that, although this command may print the following output, it still succeeds in adding the user to the admin group: `User <user> already associated with organization <org>`

Answer (score 3):

The `server-admins` group means you have permission to create and modify orgs/users, for operations within a single org (like creating a new client during bootstrap) you need ACLs within that org. Generally you get this by being a member of the `admins` group in that org, but you can also assign yourself specific permissions manually.

Comment: ACLs appear to be the answer but I can't find much info out there other than the knife acl GitHub ReadMe. None of the commands I try work due to permissions errors. Any detailed advice on what to run or how I can go about doing this myself? I am in the sudoers group on the chef server. On a side note, I really look forward to the day we move to hosted after this initial POC

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when my config.rb was misconfigured:

chef_server_url          "https://chefserver.domain.com/organizations/org/organizations/"

I corrected this and it started running correctly.